# Is it good or bad practice to inject particular beans depending on environment?

Tags: spring, spring-profiles, spring-properties

Use case: we want to apply e-mail address whitelisting in all environments, except LIVE (PROD) — here we want to send e-mails to any given address. Is it a good approach to annotate a bean that does no whitelisting as `@Profile("live")`, and `@Profile("!live")` that whitelists? Or would it be better to solve the problem with `properties` which values are different depending on environment.

Answer (score 2):

It's more error prone to solve problem with just properties when copy pasting values between properties.

If you have different profiles it's easier to manage different properties' values, Spring offer profile feature for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If it is solved with `properties` , does it mean that you have to package different JAR/WAR for different environments ?

Based on the CI/CD principle , it is better to build once and deploy the same artifact often to different environments.That means the artifact should support a way to configure the settings for different environment based on some argument , option or environment variables supplied during starting the application.

`@Profile` exactly offers such feature which allow you to configure which profile to use by using `-Dspring.profiles.active` option:

```sh
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=live application.jar
```